# Application_PreSendRequestHeaders and Application_BeginRequest in ASP.NET MVC 6 (ASP.NET 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I use these methods in ASP.NET 5 (MVC6). In MVC5, I used it in Global.asax... and now? Startup class maybe?

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;
            app?.Context?.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Request.Url.Host.StartsWith("www") || this.Request.Url.IsLoopback) return;
            var url = new UriBuilder(this.Request.Url) { Host = "www." + this.Request.Url.Host };
            this.Response.RedirectPermanent(url.ToString(), endResponse: true);
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Middleware!

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerfactory)
{
    app.Use(next => async context =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
        await next.Invoke(context);
    });

    app.Use(next => async context => {
        if (context.Request.Path.ToString().StartsWith("www"))
            await next.Invoke(context);
        else
            context.Response.Redirect("www" + context.Request.Path.ToString());
    });
}
```

Here's a good [tutorial](http://derpturkey.com/asp-net-5-custom-middlware/).

Comment: Thanks bro!! It's now like Laravel!! ;)