# Is there a way to tell IE to check for newer versions of the web page without configuring the browser itself?

Tags: c#, html, internet-explorer, web-applications

Is it possible to tell IE from front-end/back-end code to do the following settings?

[check newer versions of page every time page is visited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQ6OS.png)

[disable IE caching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3zN7.png)

I've tried adding the following headers:

```
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store">
```

but it still doesn't work since I have to set that the page be checked for newer versions of the page (see the first image).

This is a .NET MVC app

Comment: I agree with Athanasios Kataras's answer. How do you check if the page is cached? You can use F12 dev tools to check cache: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ucJj.png. Besides, I find some other threads you can refer to. You can also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948156/asp-net-mvc-how-to-disable-automatic-caching-option/12964123#12964123) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160105/disable-browser-cache-for-entire-asp-net-website).

Answer (score 1):

For MVC it is actually pretty easy:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);  
Response.Cache.AppendCacheExtension("no-store, must-revalidate");
Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); 
Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "0");
```

The meta headers are totally unreliable: [Using <meta> tags to turn off caching in all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers)

For global setting in your global.asax:

```
void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
}
```

Comment: I have tried doing this, but it seems the page is still being cached. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/uFszbtY.png) are the response headers

Comment: Your cache-control is not no-cache. It's private

Comment: how can I set the cache control?

Comment: Check the updated answer for global setting

Comment: I have [tried](https://i.imgur.com/PMfoFql.png) but somehow can't use the `Response` object?

Comment: Use middleware - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287959/application-presendrequestheaders-and-application-beginrequest-in-asp-net-mvc-6

Comment: It's .net not core.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras I got it to [work](https://i.imgur.com/ou4hTK7.png) but it still seems to cache the page

Comment: You can check if that's true in the network tab of developer tools. I doubt it does cache it. Maybe caching occurs higher up the chain (maybe web server)?

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras IE caches ajax responses for ajax calls which was causing the issue

Comment: The get requests could be cached indeed.